# ASPNET Core: Accessing App Settings in Azure that Were in Secrets

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASPNET Core site which, while running on my development machine, takes advantage of the new local secrets manager to store passwords for a few initial users. I access the secrets store via IConfigurationRoot.GetSection("username").

Here's how IConfigurationRoot gets built in Startup.cs:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
        builder.AddUserSecrets();
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
```

That final line is the IConfigurationRoot property.

This works great in development. Unfortunately, when I published the site to Azure, the passwords aren't being found. Azure doesn't support a secrets stash, but you can set environmental variables. I thought from what I read that if you use the same keys, they'll be found when the configuration code attempts to resolve a request for configuration information. Unfortunately, that's not working, so I'm obviously missing something.

Here's how I have the keys configured in Azure:

[image: env vars]

Those are the same keys as I use to successfully access the secrets stash on my development machine.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Mark, the secret `key,value` pair that you set using the tool/command line, do you have that in the `appSettings.json` right? if `yes` then and only then it can be `overrideen` by Azure's. Hope that makes sense. Basically `Appsettings.json` and `secrets.json` structure should be same to use them in application.

Comment: Thanx, JS, but I don't think that's right. At least, I seem to remember reading something that said the Azure stuff could be in some kind of environment variable. Plus, putting secret credential in appSettings.json is not something I'd like to do -- the Azure environment variables are supposed to not ever be publicly visible.

Comment: Oh no I understand you dont want the value in `appSettings.json` - what I meant is you need to have the structure in place with `dummy` values in it for the AppSettings on Azure to identify and replace - atleast this is how we made it work . I was trying to answer the second part of Azure's appSettings not being read. So in our case: we had connection strings pointing to localDb replaced by the one on AzurePortal pointing to AzureSQL

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the Secret Manager tool could help you to keep secrets out of your source code. And as this [tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html) mentioned:

> The Secret Manager tool does not encrypt the stored secrets and should not be treated as a trusted store. It is for development purposes only. The keys and values are stored in a JSON configuration file in the user profile directory.

Meanwhile, we could find that the secrets are stored in a JSON file in the user profile directory. For windows, it would be stored in the path as follows:

`%APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\<userSecretsId>\secrets.json`

> Unfortunately, when I published the site to Azure, the passwords aren't being found.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.mithunvp.com/user-secrets-asp-net-core/) to store my sensitive data in ASP.NET Core project via User Secrets, and found it could work well on my side. When publishing your app to Azure, you could leverage Azure App Services Application Settings to override the sensitive values which are stored by using the Secret Manager tool in your development. Here is a sample for you to understand it.

Assuming the structure of secrets.json file which stores your sensitive values as follows:

```
{
  "AppKeys": {
    "mark": "ABCDEF",
    "connel": "abcdef"
  }
}
```

Then you could configure app settings in your Azure Web App as follows:

[image]

For a better understanding of this idea, you could follow [User Secrets – Storing sensitive data in ASP.NET Core projects](http://www.mithunvp.com/user-secrets-asp-net-core/) and [Working with Azure App Services Application Settings and Connection Strings in ASP.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2016/08/10/working-with-azure-app-services-application-settings-and-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: Thanx, Bruce, I'll look into that. FWIW, that's the approach I'm currently following, except that the keys -- Connell and Mark -- are root-level in both the development machine's secret store and in Azure app settings. But it's good to have another link to follow.